# Bind unique href to array of li with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, menu

Well, my idea here was to create a list of possible links and to have jquery .bind() attach an appropriate href

Here's my list:

```
<ul>
    <li>main</li>
    <li>design</li>
    <li>photography</li>
    <li>studio art</li>
    <li>code-stack</li>
    <li>about me</li>
    <li>contact</li>
</ul>
```

And then my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var links = ["index.html","design.html","photo.html","studio.html","code.html","about.html","contact.html"];
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
        var thisLink = links[i];
        alert(thisLink);
        $(lis[i]).bind("click", function() {
            $(this).attr("href",thisLink);
        });
    }
});
```

So pretty much what happens is I can get it to apply things (in a previous test I got it to apply a generic "hello" alert to all of them), so it's applying it, but when I click on them...nothing happens.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are giving an attribute of href to an li element on click of the li. Why would you expect there to be something else happening ? You should consider adding an <a> tag somewhere to handle those clicks.

Comment: <li> tag can not have href attribute

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementsByTagName("li")` instead of `$("li")`?

Comment: In the past I was manually typing onClick="location.href='index.php'" for each li, wanted an easier way...  So just wrap my text with an <a> and assign it to that instead?

Comment: @MDWar yeah... you need an `<a>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var links = ["index.html","design.html","photo.html","studio.html","code.html","about.html","contact.html"];

    $("li").each(function(i, val){
         $(this).wrap("<a href='"+links[i]+"' />");
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("ul").find("li")` -- what about `$("li")`?

Comment: Oh, I like this one.  Shouldn't I keep the $("ul").find("li") just in case I end up having some uls further down the page? (considering doing light blogging on this site in the future)

The $("ul") would be more like $("#liList")

Comment: @MDWar `$("ul").find("li")` and `$("li")` are equivalent in the elements they select. If you want some more specific selector, consider `$("#some-id > li")`

Comment: Ah, I remember using the > from something else, didn't even think of that.